# Is there a, kind of, 'Crystal Ball' OOP Design Pattern?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

With regards to design patterns such as GoF, is there a pattern to decribe when one object needs to observe another object that is not even in existance yet?

i.e.

```
$crystalBall = new crystalBall();
$futureDependent = new FutureDependent();
$futureDependent->attach($crystalBall);

...

then much later
....

$importantObject = new ImportantObject()
$crystalBall->sendToFutureDependent($importantObject);

......
then later again


$strawberriesAndCreamMmmmmLovely = $futureDependent->doStuffWithImportantObject();
```

Its kind of like an observer in reverse.
But different in the sense that on observer gets notified of events.

were as this one just wants a reference to it when its created.

Any ideas?

---

Update - after commenting on Chacha102's answer i realise....Crystal Ball is a Registry...it helped by having to say the words... "difficult to get hold of"

Comment: I don't get why you wouldn't just have the importantObject attach directly to the futureDependant.

Comment: cos futureDependent is really difficult to get hold of by the time importantObject is created.

but yes...thanks...i'm tired and after a sleep i might just realise that that's the perfect simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled upon the concept of 'a Future'

See:
 * http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

```
Interface Future<V>

Type Parameters:
    V - The result type returned by this Future's get method

...
```

As discussed / referenced by:

- http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/09/temporal-coupling-in-java-and-some.html

Not sure if it is a pattern, as such.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is Reflection, where you can "analyze" a class and maybe create a new one based on what you find using clone.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Otherwise there is the "experimental" object aggregation, which isn't much use right now.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.objaggregation.php